# Return rows with one of multiple values

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL. I have a table **t** as follows:

| Id | ExternID | CodeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 2 | A |
| 3 | 2 | B |
| 4 | 3 | B |

We see that some records only have code A, others only B, others both A and B. How can I get the records with only code B, i.e., `CodeId = 'B'` but **not** `'A'`? Expected result:

| Id | ExternID | CodeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | B |

Comment: What have you tried?  What have you searched for?

Comment: Are there only A and B or others are possible as well?

Comment: A, B and others are possible.

Comment: Hello, please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in ExternID,

```
(select ExternID from t where CodeID = 'B')
minus
(select ExternID from t where CodeID = 'A')
```

If you are interested in ExternID and Id

```
select Id, ExternID from t
where ExternID in ((select ExternID from t where CodeID = 'B')
                    minus
                   (select ExternID from t where CodeID = 'A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.externalId = t.externalId and t2.codeid <> 'B'
                 );
```

Comment: This one also works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Youn can join with the virtual table that has only ids that exist only once

```
SELECT a.* FROM t a,
    (select ExternID, count(*) order by 2 having count(*) =1) b 
   where a.ExternID = b.ExternID
```

It is a bit confusing with the table aliases, but that's how it is

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option using `window function`:

```
select id, ExternID, CodeID
from (
    select *, 
        case when Min(codeid) over(partition by ExternID)=Max(codeid) over(partition by ExternID) and CodeID !='A' then 1 end valid
    from t
)t
where valid=1
```